# jQuery selector find all cells in row except given index

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

As the title, I need to do something like:

```
$('#myTable').find('td:not(0)'); // all cells except first one
```

Comment: Do you mean "all cells except the first one", or "all cells except the first one in each row" (in other words, eliminating the first column)?

Answer (score 9):

You are very close. Just use [`:eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/).

```
$('#myTable').find('td:not(:eq(0))');
```

Answer (score 3):

I assume you mean all cells in *each* row, except the first cell.

If so, you could do this.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/PDEfJ/

```
$('#myTable td:not(:nth-child(1))')
```

or you could do this, which may perform a little better:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/PDEfJ/1/

```
var result = $('#myTable tr').map(function() {
    return Array.prototype.slice.call( this.cells, 1 );
});
```

or this:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/PDEfJ/2/

```
var result = $('#myTable tr').map(function() {
    return $( this.cells ).slice( 1 ).get();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, assuming you want to select all cells except the first:

```
$('#myTable tr').each(
    function() {
        $(this).find('td:gt(0)');
    });
```

Using [`:gt()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/).

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RRtcS/)

Admittedly, this way is rather less concise than the alternative approach.